DIsplay last review on home page in Big Commerce
Is there a way to get the last review on the home page in Big Commerce without using an extension/plugin/external app? I can see that templates/pages/home.html can only access the {{products}} object as per the docs.
I can see the following code further down that file but the docs don't suggest that there is access to the {{product}} object so that seems misleading:
{{#if theme_settings.show_product_reviews_tabs}}
    {{> components/products/reviews reviews=product.reviews product=product urls=urls}}
{{/if}}

I'm using the 'Lifestyle' theme. Thank-you.
--
So prompted by @MattCoy's suggestion I'm attempting to create a widget template that I can just drag & drop on the storefront. However (shocker!) - I'm not able to get any data rendering. Here's the widget template
    {
    "name": "product-reviews",
    "schema": [
        {
            "type": "hidden",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "type": "graphQl",
                    "id": "graphQueries",
                    "typeMeta": {
                        "mappings": {
                            "productId": {
                                "reads": "product.value.*.productId",
                                "type": "Int"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "tab",
            "label": "Content",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "label": "Product",
                    "settings": [
                        {
                            "type": "productId",
                            "label": "Product",
                            "id": "productId",
                            "default": "",
                            "typeMeta": {
                                "placeholder": "Search by name or SKU"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "template": "<div id=\"sd-product-reviews-{{_.id}}\"></div>\n\n{{#each ../_.data.site.product.reviews.edges as |productReview|}}\n    <script type=\"application/ld+json\">\n    {\n        \"@context\": \"https://schema.org/\",\n        \"@type\": \"Review\",\n        \"reviewRating\": {\n        \"@type\": \"Rating\",\n        \"ratingValue\": \"{{productReview.node.rating}}\"\n                    },\n        \"name\": \"{{productReview.node.title}}\",\n        \"author\": {\n        \"type\": \"Person\",\n            \"name\": \"{{productReview.node.author.name}}\"}\n        \"reviewBody\": \"{{productReview.node.text}}\",\n        \"datePublished\": \"{{productReview.node.createdAt.utc}}\"\n                    }{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}\n            {{/each}}\n        ]\n    }\n</script>\n\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n    (function() {\n        var widgetConfiguration = {{{json.}}};\n        var dataIsNotPresent = typeof widgetConfiguration._.data === 'undefined' || Object.keys(widgetConfiguration._.data || {}).length === 0;\n        var storefrontApiQueryData = widgetConfiguration._.queryData;\n\n        function executeStorefrontApiQuery(queryData, callback) {\n            // Fetch data from the GraphQL Storefront API\n            var storefrontApiRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE compatible\n            storefrontApiRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {\n                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {\n                    callback(JSON.parse(this.response).data);\n                }\n            };\n\n            storefrontApiRequest.open('POST', `/graphql`, true);\n            storefrontApiRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${queryData.storefrontApiToken}`);\n            storefrontApiRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');\n            storefrontApiRequest.send(JSON.stringify({ query: queryData.storefrontApiQuery, variables: JSON.parse(queryData.storefrontApiQueryParamsJson) }));\n        }\n\n        function loadScript(src, onload) {\n            const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');\n            scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';\n            scriptTag.defer = true;\n            scriptTag.src = src;\n            if (onload) {\n                scriptTag.onload = onload;\n            }\n            document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);\n        }\n\n        function executeWidget(configuration, storefrontApiData) {\n            if (storefrontApiData) {\n                configuration._.data = storefrontApiData;\n            }\n            {{#if _.context.isEditorMode '===' true}}\n                var scriptPath = (build) => `https://microapps.bigcommerce.com/product-reviews-widget/${build}-bundle.js`;\n                if (window.BigCommerce\n                        && window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviews\n                        && typeof window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviews === 'function'\n                        && window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviewsPageBuilderComm\n                        && typeof window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviewsPageBuilderComm === 'function') {\n                    const productReviews = window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviews(configuration);\n                    window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviewsPageBuilderComm(productReviews);\n                } else {\n                    loadScript(scriptPath('storefront'), () => {\n                        const productReviews = window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviews(configuration);\n                        loadScript(scriptPath('pageBuilder'), () => {\n                            window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviewsPageBuilderComm(productReviews);\n                        });\n                    });\n                }\n            {{else}}\n                var storefrontScriptPath = \"https://microapps.bigcommerce.com/product-reviews-widget/storefront-bundle.js\";\n                if (window.BigCommerce && window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviews && typeof window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviews === 'function') {\n                    window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviews(configuration).setup();\n                } else {\n                    loadScript(storefrontScriptPath, () => window.BigCommerce.initializeProductReviews(configuration).setup());\n                }\n            {{/if}}\n        }\n\n        if (dataIsNotPresent && storefrontApiQueryData) {\n            executeStorefrontApiQuery(storefrontApiQueryData, function(storefrontApiData) { executeWidget(widgetConfiguration, storefrontApiData) });\n        } else {\n            executeWidget(widgetConfiguration);\n        }\n    })();\n</script>",
    "storefront_api_query": "query getProductReviews($productId: Int, $pageSize: Int = 5, $cursor: String) {\n     site {\n         product(entityId: $productId) {\n             reviews(first: $pageSize, after: $cursor, sort: NEWEST) {\n                 edges {\n                     node {\n                         title\n                         text\n                         rating\n                         createdAt {\n                             utc\n                         }\n                         author {\n                             name\n                         }\n                     }\n                 }\n             }\n         }\n     }\n }",
    "channel_id": 1
}

And just to make it a bit easier to see this is the Storefront API query on multiple lines:
query getProductReviews($productId: Int, $pageSize: Int = 5, $cursor: String) {
      site {
        product(entityId: $productId) {
          reviews(first: $pageSize, after: $cursor, sort: NEWEST) {
            edges {
              node {
                title
                text
                rating
                createdAt {
                  utc
                }
                author {
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

.. which I can see works as expected in GraphQL Playground.

Native BigCommerce reviews only exist in the context of a product, and there is no way to know which product was reviewed most recently. Therefore, there is no simple way to grab the latest product review on the homepage.

Thanks @MattCoy. I was afraid that there might be some such scenario. I'm not totally sure why they couldn't allow the dev to get an array of the products globally though - from there it could be formatted

If you want to get all products and their reviews and try to sort through them, you could use GraphQL to grab this data.

Thanks @MattCoy! - I'll give that a shot and report back

@MattCoy I'm still struggling but closer. I've posted the code in the question if you have the heart to help a brother.

I've definitely struggled quite a bit with graphQL queries within widgets. If you don't need it as a widget, you could just make a script tag in the HTML or work within the theme JS to get it going. If you do need it as a widget, you may want to fiddle around with the settings. For example, I think "type": "Int" should be "type": "Int!"

Thanks @MattCoy. I had it as "Int!", i.e. required, but kept hitting the error: "Variable '$productId' expected value of type 'Int!' but value is undefined. Reason: Expected non-null value, found null". So I changed it just to get past it. I'm wondering if you mean I can try something in JavaScript in Script Manager. Not sure how I would go about that. I thought that the widgets were for this reason - to run queries on the data. I'd love to be able to directly query the database - would open up so many possibilities but alas Big Commerce has thought better of that.

Yes, you can use the Script Manager for this. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/storefront/graphql/examples#configuring-the-request
Just put the first script there in a script tag in the Script Manager and adjust your query.
